# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'

Tags: server, python, https

Running Ubuntu Server 22.04, and I get this error when I try to run python scripts that I've been using.
The simplest case is literally just:
`import requests`

This appears to be happening system-wide, even for scripts that use their own virtual environment, which is very weird. Everything was working fine until today, and I haven't messed with pip or python packages recently. Tried looking it up, and nothing of relevance came up. Here is the full output when I try to run a script that is just: `import requests`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahmoud/http_python_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 199, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahmoud/http_python_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 199, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'
```